# Cleaning up posts only referring to dead links

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, flagging

Can we please regulate our behavior whenever we encounter useless comments or answers? I am not discussing external references. I simply want to know what I can do to get a post removed which does not give an answer itself or by reference.

For example:

- I did find an already answered question. Basically, I was satisfied. However, one post mentions useful information - the command configuring all interfaces at once.
- The link is dead. The post does not explain anything anymore. The user did not log on for more than eleven months.
- I cannot revive the question by commenting to the comment. Only by faking an answer, I would be able to advertise the issue. Otherwise, the question would not be considered a recent activity. As mentioned before, the user seems to be gone.

  ---

  [image: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-dec-mop-and-how-to-disable-it]

  ---

  I suggest to delete those posts by flagging. Or does that lower the user's reputation? At least it does give anyone who finds posts without any information a way to get them removed. Those post are plain and simple spam.

Comment: I found the comment you referenced, however while the link was misconfigured, if you correct it by removing the HTML code it works.  I did edit the comment to correct the link.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. That did turn the comment into something useful.